# How to detect if an SPI device is connected

Tags: spi

Hello I am i have connected an MCP23S17 spi GPIO expansion, upon testing it with the sample code from [here](https://pypi.org/project/RPiMCP23S17/), It does not seem to work. There could be many reasons why this is happening. I would like to narrow down the possible culprits. I would like to first know if my raspberry pi can detect the spi device. Is there an equivalent command for spi that detects if a device is present? Kind of like a ping request in networking.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no ping command.  The best you can do is send a legal command and see a legal response.

I suggest you monitor the SPI bus (MOSI, MISO, SCLK, CS) and check that the correct data is being sent, and if so check that a response is received on MISO.

If you use a bus speed in the 100 kHz region you can use (my) [piscope](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/piscope.html) to visualise the bus.

Alternatively use [monitor.py](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/examples.html#Python_monitor_py) to get a console output.

Comment: thank you for that suggestion sir, will look into it.

Comment: My current lead for me right now is that it would seem i pinned the chip select pin for  an ordinary GPIO. Although that there is only 1 device in the spi line and i have set that GPIO to low, it would still not work. I am currently finding ways of using the chip select parameter of the library, but it is not well documented if it is possible to use an ordinary GPIO as chip select. I am not well versed with python do you think you can give the [source code](https://github.com/petrockblog/RPi-MCP23S17/blob/master/RPiMCP23S17/MCP23S17.py) a look

Comment: That code only uses one of the standard chip selects CE0 or CE1 (see https://pinout.xyz/) depending on whether 0 or 1 is passed as the select parameter.

Comment: i see so unfortunately is cant be changed aside from those two, but theoretically it should still work since the chip is still receiving a low chip select, SPI communications need the CS pin to be help low at all times during communications exchange right?

Comment: Yes, CS is normally high.  When you want to talk to the chip you set its CS low, do the transfer, then set it back high.

Comment: Oh did you create this software? Amazing sir. I do have some questions on how to make it work. I was able to make it run but how do i zoom in on the reading ?

Comment: Use the up and down cursor keys to change the time-line.

Comment: Weird CE0 is being toggled what does that supposed to mean? is the library broken ? [image](https://ibb.co/1077WCy)

Comment: CE0 will be toggled by the SPI library and/or the kernel driver.  See if you can slow the bus down to see all the signals.  I can't see a clock.

Comment: Oh wait it suddenly worked when i set the speed !

Comment: I thought it suddenly work, but it would seem something just happened that made it output something random. but here is the [image](https://ibb.co/tmNdwTn)

Comment: It would seem the there is no data on MISO. I think i can rule out that the chip is faulty or damaged since somewhere along the trying to change the bus speed 7 out of 14 LEDS turned on(im using MCP to turn LEDS on/off). So far this is leading me to conclude that the library is faulty but it should be very unlikely